# Retain Git history on move directory

Tags: git

I have two scenario

1. I have a local Git repo, which I moved files into different folder and then committed. The history got lost, how can I get the file history into the moved files.
2. I have a local Git repo, which I need to move files into different folder, how to I do this without losing file history

**Example:**

```
$ git log src/main/java/com/mywork/app/App.java
commit 9408dc7ed160d2a1235a2d30ff54458fef4ec2dc
Author: xybrek <x@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 18 19:03:16 2014 +0800

    Commit src files
```

What should be here at least is the complete history of the file before it was moved. Is that possible?

Comment: Are both folders part of the same repository? Are you doing `git mv` or just moving in the file system?

Comment: Yes, in the same repository. And no, I did not do git mv, just move the file using file explorer.

Comment: Would a `git log -M -C -C --follow  --oneline -- yourFile` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The history is not lost, but you need to tell Git to follow renames.  You typically do this with `git log --follow path/to/file`.

For a little more information, Git doesn't record renames explicitly, but uses a heuristic instead.  The [FAQ entry about this](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F) says:

> Git has to interoperate with a lot of different workflows, for example some changes can come from patches, where rename information may not be available. Relying on explicit rename tracking makes it impossible to merge two trees that have done exactly the same thing, except one did it as a patch (create/delete) and one did it using some other heuristic.
>
> On a second note, tracking renames is really just a special case of tracking how content moves in the tree. In some cases, you may instead be interested in querying when a function was added or moved to a different file. By only relying on the ability to recreate this information when needed, Git aims to provide a more flexible way to track how your tree is changing.

There are also a couple of options related to renames.  Look for `.rename` in the [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page.

Comment: When I check the history of the file now, its history started from the time it was moved. So the previous history is not there. Please see my update in the question

Comment: You didn't use the `--follow` flag.  Try: `git log --follow src/main/java/com/mywork/app/App.java` as suggested in my answer. :-)  Rename detection is not on by default for `git log`.

Comment: Even if I add --follow the output is the same history

Comment: Did you commit the deletion of the old directory too?  If not, then it may look like a copy instead.  In that case, you need pass `--find-copies`, or `--find-copies-harder`.  Also, if the file changed significantly, the default similarity values may not be enough.  Check out the `--find-renames` and `--find-copies` options in the [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) man page for how to adjust these values.